# How can I get a product to be visible on a Lookup search

Tags: lookup, search, product, type

I want the product related to a opportunity to populate in the search field when I'm linking an opportunity to an Event. I've added a picklist and the product for each opportunity is visible when looking at the account or opportunity. With the way we style our opportunities, some of them are identical so I need the product to be visible upon searching. Within the Event, the field reads, 'Related to' - select opportunity, then it populates a search to link the opportunity but only gives the 'Opportunity Name', 'Account Name' and 'Account Site'. How can I get the product to populate here?